# Make head of stack not global and add possibility of several stacks (Stack implementation in C using linked lists)

Tags: c, list, stack

I was tasked to create a library that implements stack model in C using linked lists. What I did was create a user interface for stack, which allows to use it with console input, but my teacher said that I actually have to create it so it works only as a library.
The problem I am having though is that my stack head is a global variable, and all my voids are empty because of it. I cant figure out how to make it initiable in main only. Also, the program is supposed to work with several stacks if needed, and clearly with a global head it is not possible. Here is my program with additional files:

**H.h**

```
#ifndef H_H_INCLUDED
#define H_H_INCLUDED
typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;
Node* head;
int counter = 0;



#endif // H_H_INCLUDED
```

**funct.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "H.h"
void create ()
{
    head = NULL;
}
void push ()
{
    int x;
    scanf("%d", &x);
    Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    (*temp).data = x; // temp ->data = x;
    (*temp).next = NULL;
    if(head != NULL) (*temp).next = head;
    head = temp;
}
void pop ()
{
    Node* htemp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    htemp = head;
    if (htemp == NULL)
    {
        printf("STACK EMPTY \n");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        htemp = (*htemp).next;
        printf("ELEMNT TAKEN OUT: %d \n", (*head).data);
        free(head);
        head = htemp;
    }
}
void print ()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    printf("Stack: ");
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf(" %d", (*temp).data);
        temp = (*temp).next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void emptycheck ()
{
    if (head == NULL) printf("Stack is empty \n");
        else printf ("Stackas is not empty \n");
}
void topelement()
{
    if (head != NULL)
    printf("top elemnt %d \n", (*head).data);
    else printf ("Stack empty");
}
void destroy()
{
   Node* htemp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   htemp = head;
   while (htemp != NULL)
   {
       htemp = (*head).next;
       free(head);
       head = htemp;
   }
   free(htemp);
   head = NULL;
}
```

Now the part with all the switches (which doesnt have to exist, I just dont want to mess up a working program, so you get a full view.

**allinone.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "funct.c"
void stackas(){
    int choice,z;
    printf("1 - create new stack \n");
    printf("2 - push new element to stack \n");
    printf("4 - pop element from stacl \n");
    printf("5 - check if stack is empty \n");
    printf("6 - check top element of stack \n");
    printf("8 - show stack elements on screen \n");
    printf("9 - destroy stack \n");
    printf("10 - end program \n");
    while (z != 1){
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1 :
            create();
            break;
        case 2 :
            push();
            break;
        case 4 :
            pop();
            break;
        case 5 :
            emptycheck();
            break;
        case 6 :
            topelement();
            break;
        case 8 :
            print();
            break;
        case 9 :
            destroy();
            break;
        case 10 :
            z = 1;
            break;
    }
    }
}
```

And finally my main, which initiates the program (in the final release there will be no "allinone" and main will initiate the library by itself.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "allinone.c"
int main()
{
    stackas();
}
```

So as you might see this is an approach with user interface, I need to remake it only so it works as a library which understands create,push,pop,topelement,destroy commands, and returns the values + 0/1 depending if the operation was a success. I am having trouble because I dont know how to remake global head into not global, and after doing so what exactly to send to functions.

Thank you in advance.

---

---

**SOLVED IT!** Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: 1) Use prototype function declarators: `void pop ()` -> `void pop(void)`, etc. 2) You should have learned how to proceed. This is no coding/tutoring site. If you have such a basic problem, you should talk to your teacher. 3) Hint: functions can take parameters. 4) A header for a module should have the same name as the module (except for the extension). 5) Use the arrow-operator 6) Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Comment: And you have a lot of errors in your code. Too many to list.

Answer (score 0):

Start by declaring a `Stack` type:

```
typedef struct {
    Node *head;
    int counter;
} Stack;
```

Write a constructor function:

```
Stack *Stack_create(void)
{
    Stack *stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (stack) {
        stack->head = NULL;
        stack->counter = 0;
    }
    return stack;
}
```

Then define your functions taking a `Stack` as an argument and manipulating it, e.g.,:

```
void Stack_push (Stack*stack)
{
    /* Work with stack->head, stack->counter etc, here */
}
```

You will also need to write `Stack_delete()` to delete a list.

I haven't checked the logic of your code, so you will need to. You need to add more error checking, and you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()`.